# How to Find AcctCD Listed In Acumatica DAC when it Does Not Appear In SQL Table

Tags: c#, acumatica

This seems like a stupid question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

On Screen "Customers" (ScreenID=AR303000) There is a field called Customer ID.

When I inspect it, the inspector tool shows it is in the Customer Data class and has the Data Field name of AcctCD.
[image: AcctCD]

But, when I look at the Schema of the Customer Datafile in SQL Server, there is no such field. The entire list of fields is:

```
CompanyID
ContactID
BAccountID
ContactType
FullName
DisplayName
Title
Salutation
Attention
FirstName
MidName
LastName
EMail
WebSite
Fax
FaxType
Phone1
Phone1Type
Phone2
Phone2Type
Phone3
Phone3Type
DateOfBirth
DefAddressID
IsActive
WorkgroupID
OwnerID
UserID
Method
LanguageID
tstamp
CreatedByID
CreatedByScreenID
CreatedDateTime
LastModifiedByID
LastModifiedByScreenID
LastModifiedDateTime
RevisionID
DeletedDatabaseRecord
NoFax
NoMail
NoMarketing
NoCall
NoEMail
NoMassMail
Gender
MaritalStatus
Anniversary
Spouse
Img
Source
Status
Resolution
DuplicateStatus
CampaignID
AssignDate
ClassID
ParentBAccountID
IsConvertable
GrammValidationDateTime
ExtRefNbr
Synchronize
PseudonymizationStatus
ConsentAgreement
ConsentDate
ConsentExpirationDate
NoteID
```

The DAC Inspector says this:

[image: Browse DAC]

If I want to create a SQL command to view data in the database that I am seeing on the screen, I need to be able to query by AcctCD -- but I don't have that field, and I don't even see a way of joining it in from elsewhere, since there is no AcctCD in BAccount, either.

Where's it coming from? How do I get it?

Comment: I realize I can work around this by adding BAccountID to the underlying GI and then use that -- but this is an issue I run into somewhat frequently, and I would like to know how to go about finding these "missing fields" when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Customer DAC inherits from the BAccount DAC.  The Customer DAC sits on top of the larger scoped BAccount which contains all accounts (vendors,customers,employees,etc) and holds data only relevant to Customers.  They are separate tables in the DB.  For your purposes, I would join to the BAccount DAC which does contain AcctCD and not bother with Customer unless there's something specific you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow-up on a different DAC, that I spun off as a different question. If you get a chance, can you look at it? stackoverflow.com/questions/73027420